# Extra string written to file by write() in C

Tags: c, string, binary

I wrote a toy program to learn how to write binary into a file in C. I have the following program that writes integer of 1 and the string "hello" into the file named "my_log.txt", but the file 'my_log.txt' contains the following content after write: `hellowrhellowrhellowrhellowrhellowr`

I wonder why the integer (1) is missing, and where did the extra string "wr" come from?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char *filename = "my_log.txt";
    char *content = "hello";
    int i;

    int filedescriptor = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("written %d \n", i);
        write(filedescriptor, &i, sizeof(int));
        write(filedescriptor, content, sizeof(content));
    }

    close(filedescriptor);

    return 0;
}
```

I know how to write binary to file using fopen/fwrite, but I'm just testing the possibility of doing it using open/write in C.

Comment: `sizeof(content)` == `sizeof(char*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might change the line:

```
char *content = "hello";
```

to

```
char content[] = "hello";
```

Then the `sizeof(content)` in the line:

```
write(filedescriptor, content, sizeof(content));
```

Will yield enough space (6 BYTES) to write out the entire length of `content` (hello\0) instead of just four bytes.

(i.e. In your original code, sizeof(content) == sizeof(char *) == 4)

Answer (score 2):

I try it in CodeBlocks (Win version) - convert the integer to string.
I don't find a method to open write in "binay mode". Don't use sizeof() in this case, try use the strlen() function to inform the sizes of the strings. The output: 0hello1hello2hello3hello4hello --- but if you want hello0hello1hello... change the orders of the  write() functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main()
{
    char *filename = "my_log.txt";
    char *content = "hello";
    char buf[10];
    int i;

    int filedescriptor = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("written %d \n", i);
        itoa(i,buf,10);
        write(filedescriptor, buf, strlen(buf));
        write(filedescriptor, content, strlen(content));
    }

    close(filedescriptor);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***Note*** that when you use `strlen()` to get length of either a `char *` or `char []`, it is returning the length of the string not including the null terminator.  However, using `sizeof(char *)` is _different_ than using `sizeof(char [])` in that it will yield `4` for char *, but yields length PLUS null terminator for char [].  So in your example `...strlen(content));, the null terminator will not be included in the write.  In this case it worked for you, but be aware of the difference or it will cause problems for you at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You may just not be seeing what you think you're seeing.
Running your program on my system yields:

```
user@user-vm:~$ hexdump -C my_log.txt 
00000000  00 00 00 00 68 65 6c 6c  01 00 00 00 68 65 6c 6c  |....hell....hell|
00000010  02 00 00 00 68 65 6c 6c  03 00 00 00 68 65 6c 6c  |....hell....hell|
00000020  04 00 00 00 68 65 6c 6c                           |....hell|
00000028
```

As you can see, your integer is there, as a binary integer (not an ASCII value) ranging from 0 to 4, which is what you directed it to do.

Additionally as BLUEPIXY mentions, sizeof(content) will return 4 as a char* is 4 bytes on most systems, hence you're only writing out the first 4 bytes of "hello".

Try using a utility like hexdump to view your binary output in an ASCII format.

Hope that helps.